# Vectors, structs and std::find

Tags: c++, data-structures, find, vector

Again me with vectors. I hope I'm not too annoying. I have a struct like this :

```
struct monster 
{
    DWORD id;
    int x;
    int y;
    int distance;
    int HP;
};
```

So I created a vector :

```
std::vector<monster> monsters;
```

But now I don't know how to search through the vector. I want to find an ID of the monster inside the vector.

```
DWORD monster = 0xFFFAAA;
it = std::find(bot.monsters.begin(), bot.monsters.end(), currentMonster);
```

But obviously it doesn't work. I want to iterate only through the .id element of the struct, and I don't know how to do that. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Great question, exactly what I needed. Not annoying at all:)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
it = std::find_if(bot.monsters.begin(), bot.monsters.end(), 
        boost::bind(&monster::id, _1) == currentMonster);
```

Or write your own function object if you don't have boost. Would look like this

```
struct find_id : std::unary_function<monster, bool> {
    DWORD id;
    find_id(DWORD id):id(id) { }
    bool operator()(monster const& m) const {
        return m.id == id;
    }
};

it = std::find_if(bot.monsters.begin(), bot.monsters.end(), 
         find_id(currentMonster));
```

Comment: using boost, Perfect!

Comment: I wonder, if I have `{int, int}`, could I cast it to `long` and use normal find then?

Comment: What is the meaning of "bot" in bot.monsters.begin()?

Comment: What is the datatype if "it"??

Comment: good thing you gave an example without boost - we never use boost in embedded systems, it is huge.
I just didn't understand why you inherited the functor object from std::unary_function - looks like it would work either way, won't it? appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Hiyper - The type would be std::vector<monster>::iterator. Or you can use auto it = std::find_if... if you are using c++11

Comment: @tomereli IIRC it wouldn't work without it in C++03, but I think it will in C++11, which can figure out the return type itself using `decltype`.

Comment: @SemjonMössinger This was not explicitly stated, but `bot` should be a struct containing the following vector of structs: `std::vector<monster> monsters;`

Comment: unary_function is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.

Answer (score 26):

how about:

```
std::find_if(monsters.begin(), 
             monsters.end(), 
             [&cm = currentMonster]
             (const monster& m) -> bool { return cm == m; });
```

Comment: Could someone who sees this walk me through what it's doing? Specifically the [&cm = currentMonster](const monster& m) -> bool { return cm == m; });

Comment: This example uses a lambda function, which depends on C++11. `[&cm = currentMonster]` binds the variable `currentMonster` from the calling scope to a local reference in the lambda, called `cm`. Then `(const monster& m) -> bool` defines the signature of the lambda, taking one input parameter, `m`, and returning `bool`. The body of the lambda function is `{ return cm == m; }`, returning true if `cm` and `m` compare as equal.

Comment: Finally I know how to properly bind local variables to lambdas.

Comment: is the -> bool part necessary? it would compile either way, won't it?

Comment: The `{ return cm == m; }` at the end requires an `operator==` defined in the struct (see @dirkgently answer),  Without the `operator==`, change the return statement to `{ return cm.id == m.id; }`

Answer (score 21):

You need to write your own search predicate:

```
struct find_monster
{
    DWORD id;
    find_monster(DWORD id) : id(id) {}
    bool operator () ( const monster& m ) const
    {
        return m.id == id;
    }
};

it = std::find_if( monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), find_monster(monsterID));
```

Comment: Nice answer, but there is a typo in the constructor. It should be ':' not ';'

Comment: In addition to writing your own search predicate, you need to use `std::find_if` instead of `std::find`.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the `std::find` template, the third parameter especially:

```
template<class InputIterator, class EqualityComparable>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
               const EqualityComparable& value);
```

What is this EqualityComparable? Again from the documentation:

```
A type is EqualityComparable if objects of that type can be 
compared for equality using operator==, and if operator== is 
an equivalence relation.
```

Now, your type monster needs to define such an operator. If you don't the compiler generates one for you (as also the default ctor and the dtor) which does a `memcmp` sort of thing which doesn't work in your case. So, to use `std::find` first define a comparator function/functor that the algorithm can use to match your `currentMonster` i.e. something along the lines of:

```
 struct monster {
  // members
  bool operator==(const monster& l, const monster& r) const
  {
     return l.id == r.id;
  }
 };
```

Comment: Does this work? I did not have success because an operator definition inside a struct can only have 1 input

Comment: Same problem as Snoozer. -1, please complete the answer.

Comment: the concept is correct.  this works for me: `bool operator==(const monster& r) const
  {
     return id == r.id;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

or put the monsters in a map instead of a vector

or if they must be in a vector create an index map ie map of ID to vector index

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete sample based on the answer of Johannes Schaub (boost version).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct monster 
{
    DWORD id;
    int x;
    int y;
    int distance;
    int HP;
};

int main ()
{
    std::vector<monster> monsters;

    monster newMonster;
    newMonster.id    = 1;
    newMonster.x     = 10;
    monsters.push_back ( newMonster );

    newMonster.id    = 2;
    newMonster.x     = 20;
    monsters.push_back ( newMonster );

    newMonster.id    = 2;
    newMonster.x     = 30;
    monsters.push_back ( newMonster );

    DWORD monsterId = 2;

    std::vector< monster >::iterator it = std::find_if ( monsters.begin (), monsters.end (), 
        boost::bind ( &monster::id, _1 ) == monsterId );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function as below:

```
monster* findMonster(DWORD currentMonster) {
    for (auto it = bot.monsters.begin(); it != bot.monsters.end(); it++) {
        if (it->id == currentMonster) {
            return &(*it);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

It returns a pointer to the stored node if it's found in the vector, otherwise returns NULL.

Please note that `return it;` won't work directly.

Comment: How are you even compiling this? It fails on latest C++ and VS2019.