# Searching range of values in a Vector of Structs C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am writing a program to search range of values in a vector of structs, after trying for almost a day, I am still out of luck

Here is what I am doing, I know it is wrong

{in Function} 

`vector::iterator it=find_if(ip_records[ip].begin(),ip_records[ip].end(), find_it("2011-01-24 20:59.20", "2011-01-24 20:59.30"));`

{Defn}

`struct find_it {

        string start, end;

        find_it(string start, string end):start(start){}

        bool operator()(record const& r) const {

            if ((strcmp(r.start_time.c_str(), start.c_str()) >= 0) && (strcmp(r.start_time.c_str(), end.c_str()) <= 0)){

                return true;

}

}`

I am not able to receive 2 string as parameters in find_it()

Here are some links from which I could not find solution
[Vectors, structs and std::find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589985/vectors-structs-and-stdfind)
[Searching c++ std vector of structs for struct with matching string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025938/searching-c-std-vector-of-structs-for-struct-with-matching-string)
Thank you
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you mean to forget to initialize end?

Comment: Actually I am not able to do that. Whatever syntax I give, it reports syntax error.

Comment: `(strcmp(r.start_time.c_str(), start.c_str()) >= 0)` should be written as `r.start_time >= start`. `(strcmp(r.start_time.c_str(), end.c_str()) <= 0)` should be written as `r.start_time <= end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize the `end` member variable in the initialization-list:

```
find_it(string start, string end):start(start), end(end) {}
                                    //note this ^^^^^^^^
```

Now, it initializes it!

Comment: I tried all sorts of things, but don't know if I tried this. It worked... Thanks.