# STL set::find redefined search

Tags: c++, iterator, find, set, std-pair

My program is based around a set of pairs, namely

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> innerPair;
typedef std::pair<innerPair,int> setElement;
std::set<setElement> Foo;
```

The `innerPair` element is what really defines the setElement, but I need to attach a group ID to every element, hence the latter `setElement` definition.

In the remainder of the program, I need to find `innerPair` regardless of their group ID so I basically need a function

```
std::set<setElement>::iterator find(innePair);
```

that will find the innerPair regardless of its group ID. As it stands I could simply cycle through all available group ID and do multiple find() calls, but it is far from efficient.

Is there a concise way of defining a `find( ... )` member function that perform some sort of *wildcarded* search, or do I need to overload it with my own definition?

Comment: Are you saying the `innerPair` is the key, and the group ID is the value? If so, why not just use a `map`?

Comment: Looks like you actually want `std::map<innerPair, int>`.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific innerPair, or are you looking for all innerPairs with a given group ID?

Comment: innerPair are uniquely defined keys, so yes, I think that map is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple elements with the same inner pair and a differing group id, you could use [`std::multimap<innerPair, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap).

This allows you to store multiple elements with the same `innerPair`.

It also simplifies searching with `lower_bound/upper_bound` or [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range).

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible designs for this. One may be more applicable than the other.

It may be more appropriate for `innerPair` to be a struct with 3 members (first, second, and group ID) or an `std::tuple<int, int, int>`. Is the group ID part of the `innerPair` objects? If so, then I suggest this is the better design.

If not (and to be honest, I think in your situation it's not), you should be using an `std::map<innerPair,int>` to create a mapping from `innerPair` objects to group IDs. You can then find an element easily with:

```
std::map<innerPair,int> mapping;
// Fill your map
innerPair key = {1, 2};
auto found_iter = mapping.find(key);
```

You can also get the group ID for a specific `innerPair` with:

```
int group_id = mapping[key];
```

You don't need to provide a custom comparator because `operator<` is already defined for `std::pair` .

Comment: The group ID is not part of object per se. The map container provides so many interesting functions that I will definitely opt for this design, rather than struct or tuple!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search by a partial object, you are probably best off *not* to use a `std::set<...>` but rather a `std::map<...>`:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>
```

This has nearly the value type you targeted for your `std::set<...>` anyway (the difference is that the `first` member is declared to be `const`).

If you really insist in using a `std::set<...>` you'd needto create a comparator type which ignores the last `second` member. I'm not sure if `std::set<...>` supports mixed type comparisons (I *think* it does not).

Comment: As long as it provides a strict weak ordering you could just order the entire set by the `innerPair` and ignore the group id in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me to this type of container! My knowledge of C++ is still pretty restricted, as I'm not a CS student but a physics student that need to write a lot of code. Map is really what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `multiset`, with a custom comparison function, or functor for instance:

```
struct innerPairCompare
{
    bool operator () (const setElement &a, const setElement &b)
    {
        const innerPair &a_ = a.first;
        const innerPair &b_ = b.first;
        return (a_.first > b_.first || a_.first = b_.first && a_.second > b_.second);
    }

};
```

then use it for your `multiset`:

```
std::multiset<setElement,innerPairCompare> Foo;
```

It will store all the `setElement`s with the same `innerPair` in the same list.

Alternatively, if you need all the `innerPair` with a given `GroupID`, use a function comparing on groupID.

Finally, if you don't really need to keep the `GroupID` and the `innerPair` together, you could use a `map` (or `multimap`), using the `GroupID` or the `innerPair` as the `Key`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using an `std::set` then you can use [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) with a custom predicate, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589985/vectors-structs-and-stdfind).

Basically you will define a function

```
bool pairCorresponds(std::pair<int,int> element)
```

that will do the work for you.

Comment: Watch out for the time complexity.

Comment: This will run in linear time rather than logarithmic though.