# finding a value in a vector, which in turn is present inside a structure

Tags: c++, string, vector, struct

[Finding an element in a vector of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798535/finding-an-element-in-a-vector-of-structures)

this link showed me, how to look for a value inside a structure.

but i have something like this,

```
struct sample {
    string name;
    vector<string> values;
};
vector<sample>v1;
```

and this is a vector of structures. how to search for a particular string in the values vector, that is present inside the structure samples ? which itself, is a vector of structures ?

thanks.

Comment: Is the goal to get an iterator to the `sample` whose vector contains the string?

Comment: writing a find_if() as it is easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the vector v1 containing `sample` structures accessing each vector v1 member as a struct. Then, you can access the struct member vector to search for desired string:

```
for (const sample &it : v1) {
    for (const string &st : it.values) {
        if (st == ...) {
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `std::find_if` and `std::find`.

The `std::find_if` goes through the `sample` objects and checks every element with a predicate which itself uses `std::find` to go through all `std::string` elements inside and compares each of them to the token you want to find.

Here is an example, using a lambda function to create the predicate:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct sample
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> values;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<sample> const v1 =
    {
        { "one",   { "a", "b" } },
        { "two",   { "c", "token to find", "d", "e" } },
        { "three", { "f"} }
    };

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    auto const token = "token to find";

    // go through all samples
    auto const sample_iter = std::find_if(begin(v1), end(v1), [&token](sample const& s)
    {
        // in each sample, go through all values
        auto const string_iter = std::find(begin(s.values), end(s.values), token);
        return string_iter != end(s.values);
    });

    if (sample_iter == end(v1))
    {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << sample_iter->name << '\n';
    }

}
```

Output:

```
two
```