# How to use find on a vector of custom object with multiple members

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Here are my 2 structs to demonstrate my question. I have a table that has a vector of columns

```
struct column{
    string col_name;
    int index;
};

struct table{
   vector<vector<stuff>> rows;

   vector<column> columns;
};
```

What I want to do is search if one of my **table** objects has a **column** with string **col_name** I'm interested in.

I'm trying to use **std::find**, but I'm having a hard time putting the syntax together.

Say I have

```
  vector<table> all_tables;
```

How would I search a table (lets say table at index 0) to see if it contains **bacon** as the **col_name**?

So far I have

```
 find(all_tables[0].columns
```

And that's where I'm stuck. columns is a vector, and it wants an index, but I'm not sure what index to give. Do I just do columns.begin()? That doesn't seem to be correct since I have multiple member variables. I really want to be looking at the beginning of columns and the end of columns to find if it has the correct string (not int index) I'm interested in.

I understand the syntax for find is usually find(v.begin(), v.end(), "bacon"), but I don't know how to use it when it's in this scenario.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you!

----example-----

I have a table with 3 columns named "pie", "apple", and "bacon" respectively. So the size of vector columns is 3 inside my table struct. I want to be able to, given simply the table index, search through its column vector if it contains a column with the name I'm interested in.

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589985/vectors-structs-and-stdfind

Comment: can you use lambda? if yes then check my solution: http://cpp.sh/6xow2

Comment: or see this solution: http://cpp.sh/6xeaa without lamdba

Comment: @JustRufus, why don't you write answers as answers?

Comment: @JustRufus whoops, missed your answers here, you really should post them as answers :D

Comment: @user4581301 it is, but the (accepted) answer there is kinda outdated

Comment: Thank you Ap31 and JustRufus, you both helped me understand the logic a lot. I have upvoted you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) - it allows you to specify any condition as a callable parameter instead of just a value to compare to:

```
std::find_if(all_tables[0].columns.begin(), all_tables[0].columns.end(),
             [](const column& c){ return c.col_name == "bacon";});
```

The last parameter here is a lambda that returns `bool`. `find_if` will apply it to all the `column`s in the range until it finds one that satisfies the condition in the lambda (`c.col_name == "bacon"`).

You can pass any callable object instead of lambda here, e.g. `std::function` or you can define your own closure class, going with lambda is probably the most convinient way though.

Notice that `std::find` does the same thing as `std::find_if`, it just defaults to `operator==` as a condition, so another way to go is to define `operator==` for your class like this:

```
struct column{
    string col_name;
    int index;

    bool operator==(const column& c) const
    { return col_name == c.col_name; }

};
```

And then just use regular `std::find()`:

```
column sample{"bacon"};
std::find(all_tables[0].columns.begin(), all_tables[0].columns.end(), sample);
```

Perhaps your `column` objects **should be** considered equal when their `col_name`s are the same, then this second way could be preferable. Otherwise it's probably safer not to mess with `operator==`. This is up to you to decide, depending on your type logics.